# How to view my whole layout when my content goes off the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So, I know this may be a very simple question but, I have my layout in a scroll view. Everything works fine, but when I go to the Graphical layout tab in my xml file, it shows everything that would fit on the screen and not the rest of my content. How do I scroll up and down or view my whole layout in the graphical tab without having to constantly update the app on my phone and seeing whether everything is laid out the way I want it?

Comment: Even I had the same problem.... waiting to see the answer

Comment: select a device with the biggest form factor from the list in ecllipse editor apart from that you could also assign a height of 900 or so dp to the scrollview

Comment: Do not trust the Eclipse graphical layout tool.  Its so buggy that they should just remove the damn thing.  For anything non-trivial you pretty much have to use a real device or emulator, it just isn't accurate.

Comment: you can not scroll your layout at graphical tab and still this feature is not supported any android development tools like neither android studio nor eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you **just** want to "see" the content, you can temporarily add `android:layout_marginTop="-200dp"` in the child of your ScrollView, just remember to delete it again before running the app :)